Maximum principle of strong solution of linear parabolic equation in $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$
Suppose that there is a strong solution $u(x,t)\in W^{2,1}_{2,loc}(\mathbb{R}\times [0,T])$ solving the linear parabolic equation
$$-\partial_t u +\partial_x^2 u +b(x,t)\partial_x u+c(x,t) u =0\quad\text{on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$}$$
and $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Here $b(x,t)\in C^{1/2,1/4}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}\times [0,T])$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$, $c(x,t)\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times [0,T])$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$ and $u_0(x)$ is $C^{1/2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$. By Sobolev embedding, I know at least $u(x,t)$ is Holder continuous. Suppose that there is a classical solution $u^*(x,t) \geq 0$ solving the linear parabolic equation
$$-\partial_t u +\partial_x^2 u +b(x,t)\partial_x u+c^*(x,t) u =0\quad\text{on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$}$$
and $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Here $c^*(x,t)\in C^{1/2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$ and $c^*(x,t)\geq c(x,t)$. Substracting the equation, we have
$$-\partial_t (u-u^*) +\partial_x^2 (u-u^*) +b(x,t)\partial_x (u-u^*)+c(x,t) (u-u^*) \geq0\quad\text{on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$}$$
and $(u-u^*)(x,0)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
My question is do we have the maximum principle that $u-u^*\leq0$, provided that both of them having polynomial growth? The difficulty is that I do not have enough regularity on $u(x,t)$ and also $c(x,t)$.

By solution you mean weak solution with $L^\infty$ test functions?

I found a maximum principle of strong solution of in bounded domain in Theorem 7.1 of Gary Liberman's parabolic PDE book. But not sure how to extend it to whole space

Yes, I see. But how do you define a solution?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend, it is a strong solution, all weak derivatives exist and the equation holds a.e.

I see, thanks. I have an idea but I am still unsure whether it is right. Let me compute for a little while....

Sry, may take another day

Could you maybeexplain to me as well what the index $2$ means in $W^{2, 1}_{2, loc}$?

All derivatives are $L^2([-R,R]\times[0,T])$-integrable.

This argument assumes that boundary terms vanish! See mnmn1993's answer for completion of the argument.
Let me make an attempt and please correct me if I am wrong. I try to argue like in Chapter 2 "Godlewski, Raviart - Hyperbolic systems of conservation laws", which is a beautiful but rare book about conservation laws (on $(0, T) \times \mathbb{R}$). In that book, due to viscosity approximation, the authors also embark on parabolic theory a bit.
Let $R>0$ be arbitrary. First note $W^{2, 1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R} \times [0, T]) \hookrightarrow C\big([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})$ such that the below makes sense. Then multiply the PDE by $(u-u^*)^+$ and integrate. Observe for fixed $t \in [0, T]$:
$$
\langle \partial_t (u-u*), (u-u*)^+ \rangle_{H^{-1}([-R, R]) \times H^1([-R, R])} = \int_{-R}^R \partial_x^2 (u-u^*) (u-u^*)^+~\mathrm{d}x + \int^R_{-R} b \cdot \partial_x(u-u^*)(u-u^*)^+ +\int^R_{-R} (cu-c^*u^*)(u-u^*)^+ ~\mathrm{d}x
$$
Here, I am not quite sure, whether the first integral on the RHS exists, but I guess it should by $L^2([-R, R] \times [0, T])$ integrable. Integrate by parts and apply $c^*u^* \geq c u^*$
$$
= -\int^R_{-R} \big(\partial_x (u-u^*)^+\big)^2 ~\mathrm{d}x + \int^R_{-R} b\cdot \underbrace{\partial_x (u-u^*)(u-u^*)^+}_{=\partial_x (u-u^*)^+(u-u^*)^+} ~\mathrm{d}x + \int^R_{-R} c\cdot (u-u^*)(u-u^*)^+
$$
Apply Young's inequality to the second term and estimate the third one brutally.
$$
- \int^R_{-R} \big( \partial_x (u-u^*)^+\big)^2 + \int^R_{-R}\big(\partial_x (u-u^*)^+\big)^2~\mathrm{d}x + \lVert b \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})}\tfrac{1}{4} \int^{R}_{-R} (u-u^*)^2~\mathrm{d}x + \lVert c \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})} \int^{R}_{-R} (u-u^*)^2~\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$
= \left( \tfrac{1}{4}\lVert b \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})} + \lVert c \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})}\right)\lVert (u-u^*)^+(t, \cdot)\rVert_{L^2([-R, R])}^2
$$
Integrate over $t$, using $u^*(0, \cdot) = u_0 = (0, \cdot)$ to obtain the inequality for all $s \in [0, T]$:
$$
\lVert  (u-u^*)^+(s, \cdot) \rVert^2_{L^2([-R, R])} \leq \left( \tfrac{1}{4}\lVert b \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})} + \lVert c \rVert_{L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R})}\right) \int^s_0 \lVert (u-u^*)^+(t, \cdot)\rVert_{L^2([-R, R])}^2~\mathrm{d}s
$$
Thus $\lVert  (u-u^*)^+(s, \cdot) \rVert^2_{L^2([-R, R])} = 0$ for a.e. $s \in [0, T]$ and all $R>0$ by Gronwall's lemma. Hence $(u-u^*)^+ = 0$ a.e. by the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations and hence we can conclude $u \leq u^*$.
Please correct me if I am wrong or if I made some regularity/integrability mistake!

Your effort is really really appreciated!! I think the integral on the the first integral on the RHS of your first equation exists as the solution is in $W^{2,1}$, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz to separate the zeroth-order and second order terms. But I have a question on why the boundary term produced in the integration by part is zero.

I think the integration by part of the second order derivative should be
$$\int^R_{-R}\partial_x^2 (u-u^*)(u-u^*)^+dx=
[\partial_x^2 (u-u^*)(u-u^*)^+]^R_{-R}
-\int^R_{-R}|\partial_x(u-u^*)^+|^2dx.$$
I think we can consider a comparison function like $v=e^{m(n+\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon})(1+kt)}$, we first fix $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. As $u-u^*$ grows like polynomial, we can find $R>0$ large enough depending on $m,\delta$ that $u-u^*-\delta v<0$ at $x=\pm R$. We find $n$ depending on $k,m,b,c,T$ such that
$$\mathcal{L}v=-\partial_t v +\partial_x^2 v +b\partial_x v +cv=
\left(-mk(n+\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon}) + \frac{m\varepsilon(1+kt)}{(\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon})^3} + \left(\frac{mx}{\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon}} (1+kt)\right)^2 + b\frac{mx}{\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon}} (1+kt) + c\right) v<0.
$$
Then we have $\mathcal{L}(u-u^*-\delta v)\geq 0$. Now following the same arguments by @Hyperbolic PDE friend, we should have $u-u^*-\delta v\leq0$ on $[-R,R]\times [0,T]$ for every large enough $R$, then we pass $R \to \infty$ and then $\delta\to 0$, we should have $u-u^*\leq0$ on the whole space.

This looks very good and I will take another look at it! I think this is an elegant solution - indeed, there would be problems if growth is not polynomial. I completely overlooked the boundary terms because usually I work in unbounded domains with $H^m$-solutions ....
